# sorting performance less than O(nlogn)

Tags: performance, sorting

besides limited bucket sort, why is it not possible to achieve sorting performance less in run time less than O(nlog(n))?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple way to understand it.

Sorting n items is about the same as doing n searches. You're searching for where to insert each item in the table. So, take the big-O of the underlying search, and multiply it by n.

So, if the underlying search is O(n) as in linear search, the sort is O(n^2), as in insertion or bubble sort.

If the underlying search is O(log n) as in binary search, the sort is O(n log n), as in quicksort, tree sort, merge sort, etc.

If the underlying search is O(1), as in a hash search where the hash function preserves order, then the sort is O(n). Getting a hash function that preserves order is the hard part, but a really simple example is sorting a deck of cards.
If you have 52 slots, you just throw each card into its slot, then gather them up.

Comment: @rcgldr: I look at it in terms of the decisions made regarding each element. When you do a merge of two ordered lists, every comparison has an expected probability of .5 yes, .5 no (ignoring equality). That means each decision learns (has entropy of) 1 bit. So at any level n 1-bit decisions are made, and there are log2(n) levels. There are different ways to think about these algorithms, but entropy per decision is the way I like.

Comment: Deleted my prior comment. In the case of a "classic" merge sort, the number of moves is n⌈log2(n)⌉, regardless of the number of compares, so there's no "decision" factor regarding the number of moves. The "decision" factor affects the number of compares, but time complexity for number of compares is still O(n log(n)), with only variations in the constant dropped out by big O notation.

Answer (score 0):

In limited domains its possible to beat the n log n limit.

For example using a [van Emde Boas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree) is a priority queue and combining it with [Thorups](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1314692).

> Conversely, a priority queue can trivially be used for sorting: first insert all keys to be sorted, then extract them in sorted order by repeatedly deleting the minimum. Asymptotically, this settles the complexity of priority queues in terms of that of sorting.